# logstash : can't mutate a date field, but can mutate other types

Tags: logstash

```
date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  target => "ttt"
}

mutate {
    add_field => { "eee" => "%{ttt}"}
}

mutate {
    gsub => [
        "eee", "2016", "2015"
    ]
}
```

I want to change year 2016 to 2015 in my field `eee` but logstash doesn't want to change it. I tried to mutate a non-date field and it works... Why?

Comment: From a quick glance at your config, "ttt" should be a date type, "eee" should be a string, and the gsub should work.  What types and values do you get on output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
date {
  match => [ "syslog_timestamp", "MMM  d HH:mm:ss", "MMM dd HH:mm:ss" ]
  target => "aaaa"
}


mutate {
  add_field => { "eeee" => " %{aaaa}" }
}


mutate {
  gsub => [ "eeee", "2016", "2015" ]
}

mutate {
  strip => ["eeee"]
}
```

The only solution I found is to force logstash to see `eeee` as a string instead of as an immutable date by adding a leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running logstash 2, they just fixed [this bug](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-date/pull/4), so you might update the date filter.

If you still wanted to do it yourself, why not add it to syslog_timestamp (the string) before calling date{}?  You would need to modify your pattern, too.

Comment: You mean that they put the previous year if the month has not already passed by? If that's what you mean, I just installed logstash 2.1.1, and it still puts me stuff like "Dec 2016" if I don't have a year set.